# Microfrontend with react, how to pass jwt token and userID

Tags: reactjs, webpack, microservices, micro-frontend

I have started working with microfronted.Riqht now I'm struggling sharing data between two apps.

For example I have appA (container) and appB. AppA handles authentication, stores jwt token in localStorage. AppB sends requests to backend. For each request I need to add jwt token. How I can pass  jwt token and some other data(userID)  from appA to AppB ?

This is my AppA

```
import React from 'react';

const AuthForms = React.lazy(() => import('login/AuthForm'));


const App = () => {
  
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <div className={classes.contentWrapper}>
      <React.Suspense fallback={<p>Loading content from app 2...</p>} >
        <AuthForms  />
      </React.Suspense>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

AppB

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const AuthForms = () => {
    return (
        <div  className={classes.formWrapper}>
        I need jwt token in appB
        </div>
    );
};
export default AuthForms;
```

Comment: Aren't both apps hosted on same domain? If so, you should be able to get token in appB via localstorage.

Comment: @VishalRajole In development process they are on different hosts (3000 and 3001)

Comment: cookie storage would be better choice compared to localstorage as cookie gets stored for domains. (Make sure you are storing cookie without specifying port)